Error when using LYAML in Neovim plugin: "cache_loader: module yaml.version not found"
I am working on plugin for Neovim written in Lua that parses YAML data and decided to use lyaml. The plugin is working on my private MacBook Air. But when I tried to use it at work on my MacBook Pro I received the error "cache_loader: module yaml.version not found"
Here's the entire output from Neovim:
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/init.lua:460: attempt to call field 'parser' (a nil value)

# stacktrace:
  - /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/init.lua:460 _in_ **Parser**
  - /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lyaml/init.lua:487 _in_ **load**
  - /xxx/lua/xxx/model/YamlHeader.lua:114 _in_ **parseDocument**
  - /xxx/lua/xxx/controller/SetUpController.lua:37 _in_ **updateNote**
  - /xxx/lua/xxx/controller/SetUpController.lua:117 _in_ **scanNoteBoxes**
  - /xxx/lua/xxx/init.lua:13 _in_ **setup**
  - .config/nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua:9
  - .config/nvim/init.lua:2

^Ino field package.preload['yaml.version']
cache_loader: module yaml.version not found
cache_loader_lib: module yaml.version not found
^Ino file './yaml/version.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/luajit-2.1/yaml/version.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/yaml/version.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/yaml/version/init.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/yaml/version.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/yaml/version/init.lua'
^Ino file './yaml/version.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/yaml/version.so'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.1/yaml/version.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
^Ino module 'yaml.version' in file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/yaml.so'
module 'yaml.parser' not found:
^Ino field package.preload['yaml.parser']
cache_loader: module yaml.parser not found
cache_loader_lib: module yaml.parser not found
^Ino file './yaml/parser.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/luajit-2.1/yaml/parser.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/yaml/parser.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/yaml/parser/init.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/yaml/parser.lua'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/yaml/parser/init.lua'
^Ino file './yaml/parser.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/yaml/parser.so'
^Ino file '/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.1/yaml/parser.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
^Ino module 'yaml.parser' in file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/yaml.so'


On my MacBook Pro I insalled Lua 5.1 und luarocks manually,
i.e. I downloaded the source packages and installed them
with:
  sudo make macosx install

Then I installed lyaml with:
  sudo luarocks --server=http://rocks.moonscript.org install lyaml YAML_DIR=/opt/homebrew/lib/ YAML_INCDIR=/opt/homebrew/include/

Did I miss something? Do I have to specify the yaml.version in some configuration?
On my private MacBook Air I installed lyaml with:
luarocks --lua-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/lua@5.1 install lyaml
whiich installed it in ~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/lyaml. Therefor I copied it to /usr/local/share/lua/5.1:
sudo cp -r .luarocks/share/lua/5.1/lyaml /usr/local/share/lua/5.1
On my private MacBook Air the above error does not occur. I compared the instllation of lyaml on the MacBook Air with the installation on the MacBook Pro but did not find any difference. On both machines I run nvim in an oh-my-zsh in iTerm2.
I don't understand why the plugin is not working on the MacBook Pro.
Ciao
Maral
